# How to properly implement a domain object with composite id in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I have the following domain objects:

```
public class Department  {
     private long departmentId;
}
public class Manager {
     private long managerId;
}    
public class Project  {
     private ProjectId compositeId;
     @ManyToOne
     private Department department;
     @ManyToOne
     private Manager manager;
}
public class ProjectId  {
     private long departmentId;
     private long managerId;
}
```

Project is identified by a composite key (departmentId,managerId).  The question is how should Project.setManager(..) or Project.setDepartment(..) be implemented?  Is the implemention listed below the best practice?

```
public void setManager( Manager manager ) {
     this.manager = manager;
     this.compositeId.setManagerId( manager.getId() );
}
```

My understanding is that compositeId needs to be updated whenever an property is set.

A harder and related question is how should Project.setCompositeId(..) be implemented?  Project wouldn't be able to update property manager nor department based on a composite id (long).  Overwriting the compositeId without updating the properties would leave Project at an incongruous state.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ProjectId.class)
public class Project  {
     @Id @Column(name="DEPARTMENT_ID")
     private long departmentId;
     @Id @Column(name="MANAGER_ID")
     private long managerId;

     @ManyToOne
     @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="DEPARTMENT_ID", referencedColumnName="DPT_ID")
     private Department department;
     @ManyToOne
     @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="MANAGER_ID", referencedColumnName="MGR_ID")
     private Manager manager;

     ...
}
```

This mapping is very well explained in the [JPA Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships):

> JPA 1.0 requires that all `@Id` mappings
>   be Basic mappings, so if your Id comes
>   from a foreign key column through a
>   `OneToOne` or `ManyToOne` mapping, you
>   must also define a `Basic` `@Id` mapping
>   for the foreign key column. The reason
>   for this is in part that the `Id` must
>   be a simple object for identity and
>   caching purposes, and for use in the
>   `IdClass` or the `EntityManager` `find()`
>   API.
>
> **Because you now have two mappings for
>   the same foreign key column you must
>   define which one will be written to
>   the database (it must be the Basic
>   one), so the `OneToOne` or `ManyToOne`
>   foreign key must be defined to be
>   read-only. This is done through
>   setting the `JoinColumn` attributes
>   `insertable` and `updatable` to false, or
>   by using the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`
>   instead of the `@JoinColumn`.**
>
> A side effect of having two mappings
>   for the same column is that you now
>   have to keep the two in synch. This is
>   typically done through having the set
>   method for the `OneToOne` attribute also
>   set the `Basic` attribute value to the
>   target object's id. This can become
>   very complicated if the target
>   object's primary key is a
>   `GeneratedValue`, in this case you must
>   ensure that the target object's id has
>   been assigned *before* relating the two objects.
>
> (...)
>
> #### Example ManyToOne id annotation
>
> ```
> ...
> @Entity
> @IdClass(PhonePK.class)
> public class Phone {
>     @Id
>     @Column(name="OWNER_ID")
>     private long ownerId;
>
>     @Id
>     private String type;
>
>     @ManyToOne
>     @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID", referencedColumnName="EMP_ID")
>     private Employee owner;
>     ...
>
>     public void setOwner(Employee owner) {
>         this.owner = owner;
>         this.ownerId = owner.getId();
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```

#### Reference

- JPA Wikibook

  - [Primary Keys through OneToOne and ManyToOne Relationships](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships)

Comment: sometimes the answer is long enough to make me not read it completely and upvote presuming the usual correctness :)

Comment: @Bozho At least, I think this one is correct. It's also a good reading actually :)

Comment: I mapped this object using mapping xml's instead of annotations.  In Project's mapping xml, I defined an embedded-id pointing to the property compositeId, which requires a pair of get/set methods.  My question is how should setCompositeId() be implemented.  Your solution doesn't adjust this question.  Thanks.